# Proc tabulate Percentage of column SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS.  I would like to show the percentage

My code is below.

```
proc tabulate data=fall2016 missing;
class strm  Applied admitted;
table strm, Applied  admitted; 
format Applied c. admitted a.;
run;
```

Output is like this

[image]

I would like to show percent of admitted from applied, sorry about my English. I would like to do below

so 5/422   = 0.01 = 1%

417/422 = 0.99 = 99%

so I would like to show like this

```
Fall2016 422 5 1% 417 99%
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Look at using PCTN - have you tried that already?

Answer (score 0):

I googled around I figure out

```
proc tabulate data=fall2016 missing;
class strm  Applied admitted;
table strm, Applied   admitted*(n="tests" rowpctn="%"); 
format Applied c. admitted a.;
run;
```